How can I ensure whether torch.randint generate the random values at least once?
I want to generate the random value using the pytorch (or python).
I tried to use torch.randperm and torch.randint to do this.
(I guess that torch.randperm isn't proper for the following job since it only can generate the fixed number of range)
However, some of the options conflicted with my requirements.
For example, I want to generate the random 15 values from 0 to 9.
I used torch.randint as below, but it didn't guarantee that all numbers were contained in the result at least once.
torch.randint(0, 10, (15, ))
# tensor([5, 1, 0, 5, 6, 6, 0, 5, 4, 8, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2]) #Absence of 7 and 9

How can I ensure the result contains all values in the range at least once?

You can just use both randperm and randint and concatenate the results:
nrandom = 15
rrange = 10

nums = torch.concatenate(
    (torch.randperm(rrange), torch.randint(0, rrange, (nrandom - rrange, )))
)

However, you should note that because of requiring that all numbers in the range are there at least once, you'll slightly break the statistical validity of the values being drawn from a uniform distribution.
Slightly more generally (in case nrandom < rrange is allowed), you could use:
nums = torch.concatenate(
    (
        torch.randperm(rrange)[: (nrandom if nrandom < rrange else None)],
        torch.randint(0, rrange, (nrandom - rrange, )) if nrandom > rrange else torch.empty((0,), dtype=torch.int32)
    )
)

And, if you wanted to shuffle all the results as an extra step (so that it's not always the first rrange values that contain the full range of values), you could add in:
shuffleidx = torch.randperm(nrandom)
nums = nums[shuffleidx]


Thank you for your kind reply! I'll try it :)
